# Align a layout at the bottom of another

Tags: android, margins

Is there a way I can align the GridView at the bottom of the LinearLayout? I want to position (marginTop) the GridView according to the layout above it, not the top of the screen. Below is my code. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/app_background">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/begin_tour"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/begin_tour_i"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:background="@drawable/grid_border"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/link_to_page_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a relative layout. If you need it above the `TextView`, then just do `android:layout_above`. Make sure its using id then put in the id for the `TextView`. This should put it right above the `TextView`. If you need a margin just put one in.

Comment: Oh yes that should work. Thanks Grant. Totally got out of my mind.

Comment: @Heidi Would you mind accepting my answer? I kind of need the reputation

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a relative layout.

If you have a relative layout that fills the whole screen you should be able to use `android:layout_alignParentTop` to move the `Gridview` to the top of the layout.

**EDIT:**
Try this with a `layout_above`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/app_background">

    <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/begin_tour"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/begin_tour_i"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        // HERE 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/botlayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:background="@drawable/grid_border"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        // HERE
        android:id="@+id/botlayout"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_to_page_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the last LinearLayout is also android:layout_alignParentBottom. Will it put the GridView on top of the last LinearLayout?

Comment: Oh sorry it is alignParentTop but yes I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks Maxouille. I tried your solution but like I feared it would overlap the the textview at the bottom, it actually did. I want it right below the LinearLayout and right above the TextView.